# Prove that $ (a+b\sqrt{2})^n $ is of the form $k+l\sqrt{2}$.(a,b,k,l,n are integers; n>1)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I have previously proved it for n=1. Using induction, assume $(a+b\sqrt{2})^{x-1}$ is true; it is of the form $k+l\sqrt{2}$.

for $(a+b\sqrt{2})^x$; how do i proceed from here? Binomial theorem for cases where x is even or odd?

Comment: you can do it by induction or binomial theorem

Comment: I'm going to change that one $k$ to $T$ since you are using $k$ for something else now. I think we can do this: $(a+b \sqrt{2})^{k-1}=\frac{(a+b \sqrt{2})^k}{a+b \sqrt{2}}=T+l \sqrt{2} $ and then just multiply both sides by of $\frac{(a+b \sqrt{2})^k}{a+b \sqrt{2}}=T+l \sqrt{2} $ by $a+b \sqrt{2}$

Comment: Hint: by induction, any set closed under multiplication is closed under powers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo in my answer. Your edit would probable have been approved if you hadn't also added a row of stars at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binomial theorem would be one way through; then you don't need your own induction. Just note that every (positive) power of $b\sqrt{2}$ is either an integer or an integer times $\sqrt2$.

In order to use induction, for the inductions step you need to know that the set $\{a+b\sqrt2\mid a,b\in\mathbb Z\}$ is closed under multiplication. You can show that by explicit calculation:

$$ (a+b\sqrt2)(c+d\sqrt2) = (ac+2bd)+(ad+bc)\sqrt2 $$

Answer (score 3):

If $(a + b\sqrt{2})^{n} = k + l\sqrt{2}$ for some integers $k$ and $l$, then multiplying the equation by $a + b\sqrt{2}$, you get

$$(a + b\sqrt{2})^{n+1} = (ak + 2bl) + (bk + al)\sqrt{2}.$$

Since $ak + 2bl$ and $bk + al$ are integers, the result is true for $n+1$.

If you want to use the binomial theorem, a non-inductive proof may be given:

$$(a + b\sqrt{2})^{n} = \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}b^k2^{k/2} = A + B\sqrt{2},$$

where

$$A = \sum_{k\, \text{even}} \binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}b^k2^{k/2}\quad \text{and}\quad B =\sum_{k\, \text{odd}} \binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}b^k 2^{(k-1)/2}.$$